# Receiving error when trying "for" loop: arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I am trying to find the rate of change in species abundance over 3 periods (i.e. abundance.period2 / abundance.period1 * 100).

My dataframe looks like this:

```
1   Period    species   Abundance
2     1          A          10
3     2          A          2
4     3          A          4
5     1          B          5
6     2          B          20
7     3          B          0
8     1          C          1
```

I need to use a loop because I have too many species to do each individually:

```
value.final <- data.frame() # Empty data frame to fill with loop results

reps <- length(unique(df$species)) # repetition per species

for(i in 1:reps) {
  # Subset by species
  subs <- df[df$species == i, ]
  subs$species <- factor(subs$species)
  
  # Period 1
  per.1 <- subs[subs$period == "1",]
  
  # Period 2
  per.2 <- subs[subs$period == "2",]
  
  # Period 3
  per.3 <- subs[subs$period == "3",]
  
  # Value calculation
  per2.per1 <- per2$abundance/per1$abundance * 100
  per3.per2 <- per3$abundance/per2$abundance * 100
  
  # Save in dataframe
  values <- data.frame(species = rep(subs$species, length.out = 2), 
             period = c("per2.per1", "per3.per2"),
             value = c(per2.per1, per3.per2))
  
  # Bind to save
  value.final <- rbind(values, value.final)
}
```

I keep receiving the folloing error:
**Error in data.frame(species = rep(subs$species, length.out = 2), period = c("per2.per1",  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 0**

However, when I try doing it species by species without using the loop, it works fine:

```
subs <- df[df$species == "A", ]
subs$species <- factor(subs$species)

per.1 <- subs[subs$period == "1",]
per.2 <- subs[subs$period == "2",]
per.3 <- subs[subs$period == "3",]

per2.per1 <- per2$abundance/per1$abundance * 100
per3.per2 <- per3$abundance/per2$abundance * 100

data.frame(species = rep(subs$species, length.out = 2), 
             period = c("per2.per1", "per3.per2"),
             value = c(per2.per1, per3.per2))
```

I don't know how to fix the error because I don't understand why I am receiving it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you *could* approach this problem...

```
# build the data.frame you presented
df <- data.frame(Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1), 
                 Species = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 1)),
                 Abundance = c(10, 2, 4, 5, 20, 0, 1))

# split it by Species into list elements 
specList <- split(df, df$Species)

# use sapply to return a list of the differences
result <- sapply(specList, 
                 function(x) {
                   100*(exp(diff(log(x$Abundance))) - 1)
                 })

# reform the results into a data.frame and print it
print(as.data.frame(result[sapply(result, length) == 2]))
```

I'm assuming that you intended to calculate the percent increase between each of the Periods (which would be something more like: 100*(a1/a0 - 1) ) and I used the diff() function along with the log() and exp() to accomplish the division. You should use whatever method you feel most comfortable with.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What about this? No loop needed.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1), 
             Species = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 1)),
             Abundance = c(10, 2, 4, 5, 20, 0, 1))

df |>
  group_by(Species)|>
  reframe(per2.per1 = (Abundance[Period == 2]/ Abundance[Period == 1])*100,
          per3.per2 = (Abundance[Period == 3]/ Abundance[Period == 2])*100) |>
  pivot_longer(-Species, names_to = "period")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Species period    value
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 A       per2.per1    20
#> 2 A       per3.per2   200
#> 3 B       per2.per1   400
#> 4 B       per3.per2     0
```